# LaTeX table creation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, diagrams

I am new to LaTeX and really stuck in creating a table. A table created in Word is attached. Can someone help me create this table in LaTeX as it is?

[image: table]

I tried, but couldn't connect the arrows and all together.

My code so Far:

```
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{  " c |  c | c | c | c | c | c" }
\hlinewd{1.5pt}
 \rowcolor{LightCyan}
 \small\textit{g(t+0)} & \small\textit{g(t+1)} & \small\textit{g(t+2)} & \small\textit{f(t+3)} & \small\textit{f(t+4)} & \small\textit{g(t+5)} & \small{...}\\[2.5pt]
\hlinewd{1.5pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You need TikZ or PSTricks. You can find a lot of examples here at TeX.SX

Comment: Show your code. Then people can see that you have at least tried something. `:)`

Comment: Not really a table: more of a flowcahrt or similar?

Comment: How is this a try to connect the arrows? I don't see any try at all...

Comment: sorry i tried but aint working!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an attempt via `TikZ`. Here 2 line styles and 2 box styles are defined to meet the color and size requirement. same reason for the lines requirements.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  linea/.style ={draw,-stealth', rounded corners=1pt, line width=2pt},
  lineb/.style ={draw,-stealth', rounded corners=1pt, line width=2pt,color=blue!40!white},
  cell/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=gray!60!white, text width=2cm,outer sep=0pt},
  cellx/.style = {rectangle,draw, fill=red!30!white, text width=1.5cm,outer sep=0pt}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={text centered,  minimum height=2.5em, minimum width=1.5cm,node distance=0pt}
    ]

   \node at (0,0) [cell] (n0) {$g(t+0)$};    
   \node[right=of n0,cell] (n1) {$g(t+1)$};
   \node[right=of n1,cell] (n2) {$g(t+2)$};
   \node[right=of n2,cell] (n3) {$g(t+3)$};
   \node[right=of n3,cell] (n4) {$g(t+4)$};
   \node[right=of n4,cell] (n5) {$g(t+5)$};
   \node[right=of n5,cell] (n6) {$\cdots$};
%
  \node[below left = 1 cm and 1cm of n0.east,cellx] (nn1) {$s(t+0)$};
  \node[below left = 1 cm and 1cm of n1.east,cellx] (nn2) {$s(t+1)$};
  \node[below left = 1 cm and 1cm of n2.east,cellx] (nn3) {$s(t+3)$};
  \node[below left = 1 cm and 1cm of n3.east,cellx] (nn4) {$s(t+3)$};
  \node[below =0.5 cm of n4,cellx] (nn5) {$s(t4)$};

 \draw[linea](nn2.west)-|([xshift=0.3cm]n0.south); 
 \draw[linea](nn3.west)-|([xshift=0.3cm]n1.south); 
 \draw[linea](nn4.west)-|([xshift=0.3cm]n2.south); 
 \draw[linea](nn5.east)-|(n5.south)node[right,midway]{Extracted Models}; 

 \draw[lineb]([xshift=-0.75cm]n0.south)-|(nn1.north); 
 \draw[lineb]([xshift=-0.75cm]n1.south)-|(nn2.north); 
 \draw[lineb]([xshift=-0.75cm]n2.south)-|(nn3.north); 
 \draw[lineb](n4.south) -| (nn5.north) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```